# Stateless React components with controlled input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently to make controlled inputs work inside Stateless React components I am wrapping the stateless component inside a Sate full component.

For example,

```
const InputComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <input value={props.name} onChange={props.handleChange} />
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'Tekeste'
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <InputComponent name={this.state.name} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  }
}
```

What I would like to know is a couple of things.

1. Is this a good pattern?
2. If not how can I achieve my goal i.e to have controlled inputs inside stateless components.

Comment: Yes, this is a good pattern.

Comment: As far as I know, this is the ideal way to use controlled inputs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the `InputComponent` receives its value and the callback to modify it from its parent, it's a controlled input without a state. It's a perfectly good pattern, you can also make it even simpler using [ES7 class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: 'Tekeste'
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <InputComponent name={this.state.name} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  }
}
```

If you're using `create-react-app`, it's already supported out-of-the-box.

Also, you can rename the props of controlled input to `value` and `onChange` as they are more conventionally used.

Answer (score 0):

building off of @frontsideair's answer, you could do something like the following using https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/react-state-helpers

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import stateWrapper from 'react-state-helpers';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { 
      mut, 
      values: { name } 
    } = this.props;

    return <InputComponent name={name} handleChange={mut('name')} />;
  }
}

export default stateWrapper(App)
```