# Avoid to rerender on every change event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I am working on an existing React code that someone else wrote, and facing some performance issues in it. Consider the following code snippet:

```
//ComponentA.js
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    this.state = { someValue : 'dummy' }
    // Other code

    // We are using Babel, so class fields are OK
    updateVal = e => this.setState({ someValue : e.target.value})
    // fetchData makes an ajax call
    fetchData = () => { fetch(this.state.someValue) }
    render() {
       return (
         <ComponentB val={this.state.someValue} 
                     updateVal={this.updateVal}
                     fetchData={this.fetchData}/>
       )
}

//ComponentB.js
class ComponentB extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (    
        // Other code

        //Input is a component from a library
        <Input onChange={(e) => { this.updateValue(e) } } 
               onBlur={this.props.fetchData} />
               value={this.props.val}
      )
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that whenever user types in `Input`, the value gets printed after a few seconds. This is because ComponentA is actually a pretty big component (I know it's bad, but I don't want to refactor it now as it's huge and we don't have much time) and it gets re-rendered every time user types. To avoid this, I can make `Input` an uncontrolled component and update the `ComponentA`'s `someValue` `onBlur`. Another way is to have an `initialState` in `ComponentB` which is equal to the `val` prop. And `onChange`, `this.setState` is called for `ComponentB` only. Then `onBlur`, I can update `ComponentA`'s `this.state.someValue`.

However, in both these approaches, the principle of `single source of truth` of React is lost. So what will be the best solution in this case?

Here I would also like to ask, what's the harm in using Uncontrolled Component here?

Comment: You could use shouldComponentUpdate() to increase performance on component updates. I once faced a similar problem, but it was due to objects being cloned

Comment: @ZoiloReyes: Adding `shouldComponentUpdate` in `ComponentA` wont help because `someValue` will change every time `onChange` on `componentB` fires.

Comment: consider using a stateless input - no re-render until you choose - there is an example / discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476018/stateless-react-components-with-controlled-input

Answer (score 1):

A quickfix could be to debounce the `onChange` handler.

I usually use [`debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce) from Lodash but you can use another one, or write your own version.

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash'

class ComponentB extends React.Component {

    // componentA will rerender only every 300ms instead of every time user types
    handleChange = debounce(e => this.props.updateVal(e), 300)

    render() {
      return <Input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.val} />
    }

}
```

The best solution would be to split/refactor `componentA` though.

Answer (score 0):

The re-rendering is optimized (I don't think that the problem is the related to the component size).
I think that the issue is not caused by your structure (That is the one adviced by React itself) but from the Input component taken from the library.

You could also keep the state in the ComponentB and expose function to get/set values but then, as you said, you will lose the `single source of trouth` but you will avoid re-rendering every input change.

Hope this will help!

Comment: The problem seems to be with component size only. I tried the second solution I proposed, and the issue went away.